# Ant copy files without overwriting

Tags: java, ant, build

Is there any command in ant to copy files from one folder structure to another without <s>checking the last modified date/time</s> overwriting files. Basically I want all extra files from folder A to folder B. That is: **no files of folder B are replaced but extra files of folder A comes to folder B**.

I saw "ant copy" and "ant move" commands, but didn't help. Any suggestions.

Comment: did you tried use ant copy with overwrite="true"?

Comment: may I ask why you added the maven-2 tag? are you talking about ant embedded in maven?

Comment: Most people using maven came from ant background, beside that you are right, I can always embed ant in maven.

Comment: that's what I am asking: do you have an ant workflow or a maven workflow with an embedded antrun execution?

Answer (score 20):

Ant's copy task's overwrite attribute states:
"Overwrite existing files even if the destination files are newer."

So setting it to false only prevents them from being overwritten if they are newer, but if the original files are newer, they overwrite no matter what.

The only way i've found to get around this is to touch the destination files before copying, i.e:

```
<touch>
  <fileset dir="${dest.dir}"/>
</touch>
<copy todir="${dest.dir}" overwrite="false">
  <fileset dir="${src.dir}"/>
</copy>
```

Answer (score 19):

you can do it as below:

Copy a single file

```
<copy file="myfile.txt" tofile="mycopy.txt"/>
```

Copy a single file to a directory

```
<copy file="myfile.txt" todir="../some/other/dir"/>
```

Copy a directory to another directory

> <copy todir="../new/dir"><fileset dir="src_dir"/></copy>

Copy a set of files to a directory and more...

please see this link for more information.[Copy Task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html)

Comment: HOw to rename a file ?

Comment: Renames the file foo.jar to ${name}-${version}.jar (assuming name and version being predefined properties). 
<rename src="foo.jar" dest="${name}-${version}.jar"/>
If a file named ${name}-${version}.jar already exists, it will be removed prior to renaming foo.jar.

Comment: Hey thanks very much. Now <rename> task is deprecated and I could use <move> task to accomplish renaming.

Answer (score 12):

While `<touch>` works, it updates the file dates in the destination and as such it is not exactly true to the request.

According to the documentation If you have at least Ant 1.6.2, you can use the granularity attribute.

> The number of milliseconds leeway to give before deciding a file is
>   out of date. This is needed because not every file system supports
>   tracking the last modified time to the millisecond level. Default is 1
>   second, or 2 seconds on DOS systems. This can also be useful if source
>   and target files live on separate machines with clocks being out of
>   sync. since Ant 1.6.2.

just set it to a large number. I use 9223372036854, which should be about 292 years (probably this is enough). (I just chopped the last 6 digits off Long.max) which is enough to not generate warnings about dates being in the future

```
<copy todir="${dest.dir}" overwrite="false" granularity="9223372036854">
  <fileset dir="${src.dir}"/>
</copy>
```

this will guarantee that if the files are there *at all* they will be see as not old enough by the ant task and thus, not overwritten (and also not touched by another task)

Comment: Best answer since it does not modify any file attributes on the target system.

Comment: Is there a way for Ant to give a warning or a message that a file copy has not been made ?

Answer (score 3):

If there isn't an elegant solution you can always do it in a sequence:

1. `<move>` folder `<B>` to `<C>`
2. `<copy>` files of folder `<A>` to `<B>`
3. `<copy>` files of folder `<C>` to `<B>` using `overwrite=true`

(Do things the other way around, replacing the new files, not the old ones)

Comment: This didnt help because last modified date time still remains same even if the files are backed up in folder C.

Comment: So during Step 3, it doesnt replace the files because folder B (Copied from folder A) files were modified after the one in folder C, so the problem remains same.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the `<copy>` tag with a fileset as `**/*` and set the overwrite attribute to false explicitly.  I use this all the time:

```
<copy todir="/your/target" overwrite="false">
  <fileset dir="/your/source" />
</copy>
```

Comment: inculde `**/*` is redundant.  That's what `<fileset>` does by default.

Comment: It's the overwrite="false" flag that ensures files are not copied twice

Comment: That's wrong. Overwrite defaults to false, what you have above is in fact exactly the default settings of copy. overwrite="false" means don't overwrite if the target file is newer, it will always overwrite if the target file is older.

Comment: It's not because it's the default that it's wrong.  Just superfluous :)  Sometimes I find it better to repeat the default to express the intention of what you're doing.

Comment: @JoeriHendrickx it works, of course `<include name="**/*">` is not needle

Comment: @deFreitas adjusted :)

Answer (score 2):

The simple solution to your problem is to use the overwrite parameter to the copy command. This will ensure that files are not replaced

```
    <copy todir="B" verbose="true" overwrite="false">
        <fileset dir="A"/>
    </copy>
```

The more complicated example is to use a fileset [selector](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/selectors.html)

```
    <copy todir="B" verbose="true">
        <fileset dir="A">
            <present targetdir="B" present="srconly"/>
            <date datetime="01/01/2001 12:00 AM" when="after"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
```

In this example I've used a **present** selector to choose a file isn't present in the target directory (functionally the same as an overwrite check) and I've added an extra **date** condition to test if the file has been modfied since a certain date.

The [selector](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/selectors.html) list is quite extensive.