# Java: Copying external dll to output folder

Tags: java, dll, build

My project depends on a jar, which in turn loads an external dll:

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("jpcap");
}
```

The dll is delivered with the project that creates the jar (built using Ant).
However, it is not copied to the output classes folder where the main project's output are copied. Therefore I get an error at runtime:

no jpcap in java.library.path

How can I set my project so that the dll will be copied to my main project's classes folder?

Thanks a bunch,
David

Comment: does this help/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3502964/ant-copy-files

Comment: Hi @gigadot - thanks but it does not. Ant is run on the mid-level driver (the one wrapping the dll), not on the top-level project. Only the top-level project has access to its classes folder.